# Received XPC error: Connection interrupted

Tags: objective-c, xpc

I've got the following error in the Xcode console:

> Received XPC error Connection interrupted for message type 3 kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery.

By the way, I used Xcode 9.0 and language was Objective-C.

And I also want to know the meaning of `kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery`.

Comment: I encountered this issue too. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any solution for this ? My XCode version is 9.3. For me I have no idea what causes the issue. It was working and some event or somethings making this issue to appear.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?